# Proof by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i/2^i=2-(n+2)/2^n$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}.$$

this is a question that must be proved by induction. For the base case I used $n=1$ and simplified to $1/2$ and now for the inductive step
$$p(k)\to p(k+1)=2-\frac{(k+1)+2}{2^{k+1}}.$$
I am not sure if this is right step or if I should simply be $p(k)+(k+1)$.

Comment: A basic introduction [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You need to use $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i/2^i  =\sum_{i=1}^{k} i/2^i  + (k+1)/2^{k+1}$.

Comment: is that implying to sub in(k+1)? @ArcticChar

Comment: A strategy for *all* induction proofs about sums.  To prove $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = f(n)$, then for the induction step can *ALWAYS* but $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k = a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n a_n = a_{n+1} + f(n)\underbrace{=}_{to\ prove}f(n+1)$.   So to do an induction step about sums it is *ALWAYS* sufficient to prove $ a_{n+1} + f(n)=f(n+1) $.  The will *always* work (if it can be done) and that should *always* be your first strategy.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks I think I get it now, instead of adding k+1 I am supposed to add the previous term to the next term since it is the sigma notation

Comment: So if you can prove $\frac {n+1}{2^{n+1}} + (2 -\frac {n+2}{2^n})=2 - \frac {(n+1)+2}{2^{n+1}}$ you are done.  That will prove your induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}$ for some $n$.

Induction step:  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{blue}{n+1}} \frac{i}{2^i}=\color{blue}{\frac {n+1}{2^{n+1}}} + (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n}} \frac{i}{2^i})=$

$\frac {n+1}{2^{n+1}} + (2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}) =$

$.........=$

$2 - \frac {(n+1)+2}{2^{n+1}}$

Can you fill in the missing step?